# Magical equations in statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Studying ensembles in Statistical Mechanics I have found some formulas such as 
$$ S = k\frac{\partial}{\partial T} (T\ln Z) $$ 
or 
$$ \langle E \rangle = -\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta} \ln Z $$ 
or
 $$ \langle \Delta E ^2 \rangle = - \frac{\partial \langle E \rangle}{\partial \beta}$$ 
among many others. These formulas are mostly derived in the scope of one particular ensemble and, at least in the bibliography I am reading, they give no argument other than "if we do this calculation it just works". But they give no physical reasons for this to be so. Then I see that every one uses this formulas in any other ensemble as if they were a general result with no proof.

Are this kind formulas valid in general for any distribution? If so, why? Or are they valid only for some special distributions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These three relations are only  valid in the **canonical and grand canonical ensemble**. Let's analyze them one by one:

**Relation n. 1:**
$$S = k \frac{\partial{(T \log Z)}}{\partial T}\tag{1}\label{1}$$

**Valid in canonical and grand canonical ensemble. Formally valid in the mircocanonical.**

From thermodynamics, we know that entropy can be calculated from the Helmholtz free energy $F(N,V,T)$ as

$$S=-\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_{N,V} \tag{1a}\label{1a}$$

as it follows from the fact that $dF=-SdT-PdV+\mu dN$.

In the canonical ensemble, the partition function $Z_c(N,V,T)$ is connected to  $F(N,V,T)$ by the following relation:

$$F(N,V,T)=-kT\log(Z_c(N,V,T)) \tag{1b}\label{1b}$$

It follows from \ref{1a} and \ref{1b} that

$$S = -\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_{N,V} = k \frac{\partial{(T \log Z_c)}}{\partial T} \tag{1c}\label{1c}$$

which is just \ref{1c}.

But we also know that entropy can be calculated from the Landau free energy $\Omega (\mu, V, T)= - PV$:

$$S=-\left(\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial T}\right)_{\mu,v}\tag{1d}\label{1d}$$

as it follows from $d\Omega=-SdT-PdV-N d\mu$.

In the grand canonical ensemble, the partition function $Z_{gc}(\mu,V,T)$ is connected to the Landau free energy by the relation

$$\Omega= -kT \log(Z_{gc}(\mu,V,T))\tag{1e}\label{1e}$$

It readily follows from \ref{1d} and \ref{1e} that

$$S = -\left(\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial T}\right)_{\mu,V} = k \frac{\partial{(T \log Z_{gc})}}{\partial T} \tag{1f}\label{1f}$$

which is analogous to \ref{1c}.

In the micro canonical ensemble, we have

$$S=k \log(Z_{mc}(N,V,E))$$

so \ref{1} is *formally* valid again. However, $T$ is not a parameter in the microcanonical ensemble, so I hesistate to say that \ref{1} is valid. But for sure you can use it.

For the other relations, I will be quicker.

**Relation n.2**

$$E \equiv \langle \mathcal H\rangle = -\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

where $\mathcal H$ is the Hamiltonian.

**Valid in canonical and grand canonical. No meaning in the microcanonical**

Since the canonical and microcanonical partition functions have the same dependence on $\beta$, \ref{2} applies in both ensemble. However it has no meaning in the microcanonical ensemble, where $E$ is a parameter.

**Relation n. 3**

$$\Delta E^2 = -\frac{\partial E}{\partial \beta} \tag{3}\label{3}$$

**Valid in canonical and grand canonical. No meaning in the microcanonical**

This one follows from \ref{2}, together with

$$\Delta E^2 = k T^2 C_V \tag{3a}\label{3a}$$

and

$$C_V = -\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}\tag{3b}\label{3b}$$

and

$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}=-kT^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\tag{3c}\label{3c}$$

From these relations, you get \ref{3}. Once again, this has no meaning in the microcanonical ensemble, where $E$ is fixed and therefore there are no energy fluctuation.

If you are looking for books that deal with these issues properly, I suggest Kerson Huang, *Statistical Mechanics* or Mark Tuckerman, *Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Molecular Simulation*. You can find Tuckerman's lecture notes [here](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/stat.mech/lectures.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't the particular case of the formula $ S = k \frac{\partial}{\partial T} (T\log (Z)) $ valid for the three canonical ensembles (microcanonical, canonical and grand canonical)? It is generally derived into the canonical but if $Z = \frac{1}{\Omega}$ (i.e. the microcanonical partition function) then we recover $S=-k \log Z_{mc}$ and for the grand canonical, according to D. Tong's notes on statistical physics eq. (1.40) (you can find them freely with Google), it seems to also be valid. 
Thanks also for your book recomendation, I will check them.

Comment: @user171780 I was wrong. Check updated answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer, thanks. So in conclusion, this and other "magical formulas" are not of general validity, they are mere coincidences and easy-to-calculate ways to obtain certain magnitudes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The partition function is defined as a sum over microstates at a specific temperature (with $\beta = 1/kT$)

$$Z(\beta) = \sum_s e^{-\beta E_s}$$

where $E_s$ is the energy of the microstate $s$.

Recall that if our system is connected to a large heat bath at temperature $T$, the probability for our system to be in state $s$ is

$$\text{Prob}(s) = \frac{e^{-\beta E_s}}{Z(\beta)}.$$

That means that the expected energy $\langle E \rangle$ is

$$\langle E \rangle = \sum_s E_s \text{Prob}(s) = \frac{\sum_s E_s e^{-\beta E_s}}{Z(\beta)} = \frac{- \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} Z(\beta)}{Z(\beta)} = - \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \ln(Z(\beta)).$$

The other identities can be derived using similar manipulations.